# How to remains the total balance if the cashtendered is > total amount

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(function() {
    $("#payment").on("keydown keyup", sum);
 function sum() {

  const balance=Number.parseFloat(document.getElementById('balance').value);
    var payment = Number.parseFloat(document.getElementById('payment').value);
    var amount = Number.parseFloat(document.getElementById('amount').value);

     if(payment<amount){
     

        let TotalBalance = balance;  
      TotalBalance = TotalBalance + (amount - payment); 
      document.getElementById('tbalance').value=TotalBalance;
    }
 }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2">
        Amount<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" class="form-control" />
        </div>
     
        <div class="col-md-2">
        Cash Tendered </strong>: <input type="text" name="payment" id="payment" class="form-control" />
      
        
         <div class="col-md-2">
        Previous Balance</strong>: <input type="text" name="balance" id="balance"readonly="" class="form-control" value="40" />
        </div>

         <div class="col-md-2">
       TOtalBalance</strong>: <input type="text" name="tbalance" id="tbalance"readonly="" class="form-control" value="40" />
        </div>
```

Hello, Guys, my problem is if the Cashtendered > Total Amount I want the Total Balance remains 40. Because, The cash tendered is the patient paid to the total amount. For example if the customer has Previous balance is 40 and the customer comes back and buys something and the total amount of the customer is 20 and the customer paid 50 so that the balance remains 40 because the cashtenered > Total amount. because in my code, for example, the total balance is 40 and i type 100 in Amount and 500 in cash tendered the total balance becomes 90 I want to remains 40. I searched for this problem the missing part in this tbalance id is the Parsefloat but i don't know how to apply this

Comment: this is simple maths ... closing balance = opening balance + new charges - payments made - not sure what your code is even doing - you don't do yourself any favours by calling the variables textvalue1 instead of, say payment

Comment: ok sir i changed the variables

Comment: It's because you do calculactions on every key event ... so what you see is the result of when the payment was 50, and nothing is done once the payment becomes 500 (due to the if statement)

Comment: sir @JaromandaX what's your suggestion here?

Comment: do a calculation of all conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {

    $("#payment").on("keydown keyup", sum);
 function sum() {
var balance=Number.parseFloat(document.getElementById('balance').value);
    var payment = Number.parseFloat(document.getElementById('payment').value);
    var amount = Number.parseFloat(document.getElementById('amount').value);
   if (payment>=amount) {
 
  

    document.getElementById('tbalance').value=balance;
   }
    else if(payment<amount){

      
      TotalBalance = balance+ (amount - payment); 
      document.getElementById('tbalance').value=TotalBalance;
    }
 }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="col-md-2">
        Amount<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" class="form-control" />
        </div>
       
      
        <div class="col-md-2">
        Cash Tendered </strong>: <input type="text" name="payment" id="payment" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      
        
         <div class="col-md-2">
        Balance</strong>: <input type="text" name="balance" id="balance"readonly="" class="form-control" value="40"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
       TOtalBalance</strong>: <input type="text" name="tbalance" id="tbalance"readonly="" class="form-control" value="40" />
        </div>
```